# Static electricity high voltage and charge difference

Tags: static-electricity

I have often heard heard voltage being described as a difference in charge between two points. If this is true, how is static electricity such high voltage even though it is a relatively small difference in charge?

Comment: the narrower a container is, the higher the fluid level for the same amount of water

Comment: The difference in charge between two points is related to the \$\mathscr{E}\$-field, which is measured in units of volts/meter, not volts. This is also known as Newtons/Coulomb. So what someone else said, or you read about, wasn't correctly picked up by your interpretation, I suspect, regardless of how often you heard/read it.

Answer (score 3):

Q = C·V

Hence, if C (capacitance) is small then, for a given charge (Q), the voltage will be high.

> I have often heard heard voltage being described as a difference in
>   charge between two points.

Maybe you need to check that definition.